# F curve modifier and Evaluation time, Will not allow me to delete the f curve mod then edit keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have a character with a cycling walk animation in the nla editor. The character is set up to follow a path/bezier curve. This works fine and I used an F-curve modifier to get a consistent speed along the path. Now I need to add stopping and jumping etc.When i try to keyframe the path Evaluation Time it won't let me, claiming there is something locked or modified. So i Have tried to bake the f curve, and I have tried disabling the f curve modifier with the checkbox, the wrench(es) and even deleted it entirely. None of these allow me to edit the keyframes of the path's Evaluation Time. (The Evaluation Time has the F curve modifier/had it before being deactivated). Using Additive does not work either.

Every combo repeats the error F-Curve with path 'eval_time[0]' cannot be keyframed, ensure that it is not locked or sampled, and try removing F-Modifiers

I have definitely tried to remove the F modifier but maybe it is somehow still locked or sampled (?) really can't find any info on this that doesn't make it seem like I've done the right things and its just not working for me. Thanks to anyone who can help figure this out

Answer (score -1):

SIGH. How unintuitive. Apparently if you UNBAKE the F-curve in question it will convert it 'back to keyframes' I guess I did start out with a single keyframe and then animated it with the modifier. So this makes sense, but is so counterintuitive because usually you are going to get the keyframes from baking something. I clicked Bake multiple times with no effect before posting this and decided why not try clicking the Unbake option... and that fixed my issue. hope this can help someone else having a battle with their F-curves.

Comment: If you're going to downvote please tell me why so I can improve/understand.

Comment: I'm wondering this sometimes too, when my answers get downvoted, In your case I would guess it's simply because instead of giving an objective solution it's mostly a rant about how unintuitive it is.